# Error when data is bind into data table or gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'DADE' to data type int.

**SQL command** which i use is this:

```
SELECT * FROM p_details 
WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%has%ln%' 
AND  
  CODE = 13 
AND 
  T_CODE='H'
```

**My code is:**

```
SqlDataReader drr = com4.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(drr); <--error line
GridView7.DataSource = dt;
GridView7.DataBind();
```

Comment: please put some more code should not come that error because you are not converting DADE

Comment: This is the only thing i am having ,getting data from database and closing the connection.In database table all column as varchar ,but i don't know why it is converting to int.

Comment: Try to use a `SqlDataAdapter` instead: `using(var da=new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))da.Fill(dt);`

Comment: post your gridview markup here

Comment: @TimSchmelter What `SqlDataAdapter` will do in this case?

Comment: show us the exception message

Comment: @Shaharyar:  i guess it won't make a difference. I wasn't sure, that's why i said that he could test it. I'm normally using `DataAdapter.Fill` but what i've read now there should be no difference regarding to this issue.

Comment: @krishnakumar do you have value 'DADE' in your table

Comment: @krishnakumar: You state that all columns are varchar and you don't convert anything to int but your sql is `WHERE CODE = 13`. If code is also a varchar you are converting 13 to it. You have a value `DADE` in one of your columns. Which column is it and where do you access this column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a  comment you state that all columns are `varchar` and you don't convert anything to int but your sql is `WHERE CODE = 13`.

So `code` is also a `varchar`. By comparing it with the `int` 13 you don't convert 13 to `varchar` but vice-versa, you are converting every value in `code` to an `int`.

Why? Because of the [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) rule:

- the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence

`int` has a higher precedence so all `varchar` values are converted to `int`. I assume you have a value `'DADA'` in that column which cannot be converted to `int`.

So the solution is simple, make it a `varchar` by using `'13'` instead of `13`:

```
SELECT * FROM p_details 
WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%has%ln%' 
AND  
  CODE = '13' 
AND 
  T_CODE = 'H'
```

Apart from that you should always use sql parameters to prevent sql-injection:

```
SELECT * FROM p_details 
WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE @lowname
AND  
  CODE = @code 
AND 
  T_CODE = @tCode

com4.Parameters.Add("@lowname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + name.ToLower() + "%");
com4.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = code;
com4.Parameters.Add("@tCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tCode;
```

Comment: Worked like charm, i was thinking any way it will be converting int to varchar blinding with out thinking about data type precedence, Thanks.

Comment: @krishnakumar: you see how important it is to always use the correct type and to avoid implicit conversions.

Comment: Yes sir, a biggest lesson learned in start of my career from you.thanks.